# Specified source 'MySource' is invalid

Tags: jenkins, nuget

I am updating Jenkins Pipeline for nuget package publishing. Everything is working perfectly expect a last step which is a bat command.

When I run following command in command line it works:

```
C:\Host\packages\release\nuget.exe push -Source MySource -ApiKey VSTS C:\Host\packages\release\CoreLogger.2.1.109.nupkg
Pushing CoreLogger.2.1.109.nupkg to 'C:\Host\packages'...
Your package was pushed.
```

It works.

I copy the same line and put it in my pipeline like:

```
bat "C:\\Host\\packages\\release\\nuget.exe push -Source MySource -ApiKey VSTS C:\\Host\\packages\\release\\CoreLogger.2.1.${BUILD_NUMBER}.nupkg"
```

if return following error!

```
C:\Host\packages\release\nuget.exe push -Source MySource -ApiKey VSTS C:\Host\packages\release\CoreLogger.2.1.109.nupkg
The specified source 'MySource' is invalid. Please provide a valid source. 
script returned exit code 1
```

What could have been gone wrong?

Comment: Have you added the source? Is that enabled in your source list?

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres thanks for following up on this. It is been long time I can not remember how I solved it, I should have left an answer. :) Enjoy your day "Aproveite seu dia"

Answer (score 1):

The source is defined in your nuget.config file, and nuget.exe finds it by looking in the "current directory" and recursing up to the root directory. If the "current directory" when run on your build server isn't where you have your nuget.config, or a subdirectory under it, nuget.exe won't find it.

So, check your build configuration to make sure the current directory is where your nuget.config is. Or, you can pass the -ConfigFile parameter and explicitly tell it where the config file is.

Comment: Thanks for answering, The same environment works in command line but not in Jenkins

Comment: I have already published it and it works, my intention was to push the published to private nuget server

Comment: Have you tried putting `echo %cd%` in your bat file to make sure the nuget.exe command is running from where you expect?